# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, php-7

I am new to laravel i am trying to insert data to database and i am getting this error

[image]

this is my table its have no date fields

[image]

controller and insert code

```
public function save_data(Request $request){

$data= $request->all();
$name=$data['name'];
$insert=array('name'=>$name);
DB::table('data')->insert($insert);
}
```

Comment: You are storing name in type `int(11)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `name` column is of type `int(11)`. It expects an integer, not a string (`VARCHAR`). Change your column type (preferably with a `migration`) from `int(11)` to a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: In his table migration, he'll probably want to change it to `$table->string('name');`, which should produce that result in the table column.

Comment: Yes but do note that it is a migration to update an existing table, so it should be: `$table->string('name')->change();`. Otherwise he will get an error saying: `column "name" already exists on this table`.